# Compress-Archive error: not a supported format

Tags: powershell

I created this script to compress some folder:

```
$timer = (Get-Date -Format yyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss)
$version = 1.1.2
$folder = New-Item -Name "test_$vesion_$timer" -ItemType directory
Copy-Item -Path test1\log -Destination $folder -Recurse
Compress-Archive -Path $folder -DestinationPath $folder
Remove-Item $folder  -Recurse
```

But when I try it, I get this error:

```
Compress-Archive : 1.1.2_2017-06-05_08-58-19 is not a supported archive file format. .zip is the only supported archive file format.
+ Compress-Archive -Path $folder -DestinationPath $folder
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (1.1.2_2017-06-05_08-58-19:String) [Compress-Archive], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedArchiveFileExtension,Compress-Archive
```

Comment: You set `$version` but then use `$vesion` (missing R) in the next line so your folder won't be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving the zip file the same name as the folder, which in your example is `test_1.1.2_2017-06-05_08-58-19`. The problem is that the `.` character introduced by your `$version` variable makes the rest of the name look like a file extension. If you give the archive an extension other than `.zip`, the `Compress-Archive` cmdlet will return this error.

You should be able to fix this by simply adding `.zip` to the end of the archive name, like so:

```
Compress-Archive -Path $folder -DestinationPath "$folder.zip"
```

Comment: when i do this changement i get this :Compress-Archive : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'DestinationPath'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
v1.0\backup_before_update.ps1:14 char:49
+ Compress-Archive -Path $folder -DestinationPath $folder.zip

Comment: @h.s did you put the destination path value in double-quotes as above?

Comment: Compress-Archive -Path $folder -DestinationPath "$folder.zip" i dont have erreur now but the name of my folder still only test_2017-06-05_08-58-19 so the vision is not added to folder name

Comment: i have a good result when i make this changement                                                 $folder = New-Item -Name ('test_'+'V'+ $version+'_' + $timer) -ItemType directory

Comment: Try putting your version value in quotes like this `$version = "1.1.2"` and you might also want to put braces around the variable name when you use it in the `New-Item` command so the underscore doesn't confuse PowerShell, like this `$folder = New-Item -Name "test_${version}_$timer" -ItemType directory`